# PHP Pagination, values gets reset to default when pressing next

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, pagination

have created a website that is displaying bookings from a database. I'm only displaying 10 bookings per page, so I have created a pagination aswell. To get the bookings you have to set an ID, and I made everything work if I code the ID directly into the php-file. The thing I'm trying to do now is to get a select-form, so the user is able to select the ID by its own.

I created a select-form where I display all the IDs as options and I'm able to choose an ID and get out bookings, but when I press the "next" button everything disappears. If I now choose the ID again and update the page, then all the bookings for page 2 will appear. It seems like the values reset to default, but I want them to stay the same everytime you press "Next". How can I solve this? Very thankful for any help!

In ?page=1 this will display the ID, when I press "Next" and enter ?page=2 it echoes "no id selected"

```
if(isset($hejsann[$Option])) {
    echo $hejsann[$Option];
} else { 
    echo "no id selected";
}
```

This is the select-form where I choose the ID

```
<form method="post">
<fieldset>
<select name="taskOption" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose a group</option>
<?php

     if (isset($_POST['taskOption'])) { 
        $Option = $_POST['taskOption'];
       }
    while($hej < count($hejsan)) {
            if($hej==$_POST['taskOption']){
               $selected = "selected=selected";
             }else{
               $selected = "";
             }
        echo '<option value="' . $hej . '" '.$selected .'>' . $hejsan[$hej] . '</option>';
        $hej++;
    }

    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Find bookings">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the pagination

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['taskOption'];
$book = bookings($hejsann[$var]);

$page = (int) $_GET['page'];
if ($page < 1) $page = 1;

$resultsPerPage = 10;
$startResults = ($page - 1) * $resultsPerPage;
$numberOfRows = count($book);
$totalPages = ceil($numberOfRows / $resultsPerPage);

$output = array_slice($book, $startResults, $resultsPerPage);

$b = 0;
while($b < count($output)) {
echo $output[$b];
$b++;
}

if($page > 1) {
echo '<a href="?page='.($page - 1).'"><span>Back</span></a>&nbsp';
}

for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
{
if($i == $page)
    echo '<strong>'.$i.'</strong>&nbsp';
else
    echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'"><span style="margin-left: 15px;">'.$i.'</span>    </a>&nbsp';
}

if ($page < $totalPages) {
echo '<a href="?page='.($page + 1).'"><span style="margin-left: 15px;">Next</span></a>&nbsp;';
}

if($page == $totalPages && $page > 1) {
echo '<a href="?page=1"><span style="margin-left: 15px;">First</span></a>&nbsp';
}
?>
```

Comment: I was thinking about using session, but I don't know how to do it when it's all in the same file, I only link page.php?page=1 to page.php?page=2

Comment: Not clear on how these snippets fit together. Are they all on the same page? Are you clicking a link, or doing something with the select to get to the next page? If you just enter page=2, then taskOption will not be set...

Comment: I think that's what I'm trying to fix, so the taskOption is the same in page=1 and in page=2. Fixed so taskOption = 0 if you haven't submitted the form

Comment: Everything is in the same document, the amount of pages depends on how many bookings that are going to display. If there exists more than 10 bookings, ?page=2 will be created, if more than 20 bookings then ?page=3 will be created

Comment: So, the problem you have, is that when you submit the form, the `?page` is not being included in the url? You say that $hejsann[$Option] is not being set, but I don't see where it is supposed to be.

Comment: It seems like $_POST['taskOption'] wont remain set when I go from page=1 to page=2

Comment: Oh, I see - you're clicking the link, and you want it to remember the POST data - that right?

Comment: Exactly, but I fixed it now by adding ?id=' . $id . ' to the href

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` data is not automatically included in the get string when you click a link. Links can't include post data, as they are pure text strings. To pass another value through the link, you need to add it to the GET string of the url. Use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to generate a get string from an array, for instance:

```
echo $url.'?'.http_build_string($_POST);
```

To output a url with the post data received by the page added to the url.